# Multi langauge Translate options in Java Springboot Project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, eclipse, arabic-support

I have a System which has English as default language and Arabic as the 2nd language, so that an user can change to Arabic if needed. This is set ap with a key and value pair in the `properties` file, like `text_en` and `text_ar`. When I try to do this through my computer using eclipse its working perfect: when I click Arabic, the language is switching. But when I deploy the application to the server or when I just run it on other PCs, I only get unicodes of the Arabic language.

I have tried troubleshooting this issue in many ways to but nothing worked for me up to now.

If anyone has faced this issue before or anyone knows what will be the fix, please send an reply.

**Thank you**

Comment: Hello, this looks unanswerable withou more detailed look on your sourcecode. How is your localization reflected in frontend code?